# How to change text color of pie chart description in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I am creating a pie chart using the MPAndroidChart library. In my app, I am having a black background and the text color of the pie chart description is grey be default which is not good for me. I am not able to change it.

How do I change the text color of the description?

My pie chart: 
      [image]

Comment: Please don't repeat your Question , just edit your existing Question and it will bump into the Queue above.

Comment: wow ... i did not know this .... Thanks jay for this new tip :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `setDescriptionColor(int color)` method

`chart.setDescriptionColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));`

Answer (score 1):

For now, things I little bit changed. So, the latest known for me solution would be:

```
description.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color));
```

where `description` stand for `Description description = new Description();`

Answer (score 0):

Text color also you can change from here.

1. Into your Library **"MPChartLib"**
2. First Go:- Package:- Chart---> Chart.java
3. Then Go:- init();
4. Change Pie Chart Discription text color:-

I found this code which might be helpful [here](https://github.com/crashlytics/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/Chart.java).

> ```
>     public void setDescriptionColor(int color) {
>         mDescPaint.setColor(color);
>     }
> ```

Change other texts Color From here:-

The code below is from the same source.

> ```
>             mDescPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
>             mDescPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
>             mDescPaint.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);
>             mDescPaint.setTextSize(Utils.convertDpToPixel(9f));
>             mInfoPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
>             mInfoPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0)); // black
>             mInfoPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
>             mInfoPaint.setTextSize(Utils.convertDpToPixel(15f));
>             mDrawPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
> ```